# Raster Calculator returns strange values

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I am using the raster calculator on QGIS to calculate a spectral index from a raster.
The formula is the following (it says it's valid):
`( "CASI_Noon_III@50" - "CASI_Noon_III@43" ) / ( "CASI_Noon_III@50" + "CASI_Noon_III@43" )`

When I save the new calculated raster something like this appears
[image: New calculated raster]

The raster doesn't show, same if I try to change the min/max rendering options.

The same happens if I only type in the raster calculator something like `"CASI_Noon_III@50"` that should work ok as both of the bands appear normal.

If I type `If("CASI_Noon_III@50" AND "CASI_Noon_III@43", ("CASI_Noon_III@50"-"CASI_Noon_III@43")/("CASI_Noon_III@50"+"CASI_Noon_III@43", 0)`
only a portion, let's say 10% of the original raster is calculated.

What's happening?!